# Robust Random Number Generation

Tags: c#, c++, random, mersenne-twister

I'm looking for a performant, reasonably robust RNG using no special hardware. It can use mathematical methods (Mersenne Twister, etc), it can "collect entropy" from the machine, whatever. On Linux/etc we have a `drand48()` which generates 48 random bits. I'd like a similar function/class for C++ or C# which can generate more than 32 bits of randomness and which low-order bits are equally as random as high-order bits.

It doesn't have to be cryptographically secure but it must not use or be based on the C-language `rand()` or .NET `System.Random`.

Any source code, links to sources, etc. would be appreciated! Failing that, what TYPE of RNG should I be looking for?

Comment: Why not `System.Random`?  I know that `rand` is poor, is `System.Random` poor as well?  If so, that's sad :(

Comment: The justification for closing this question does not seem correct at all.

Comment: @bames53 I've posted a reopen vote now. You seem to have enough rep too, so do it. :-D

Comment: I suppose that now you can<br/>simply google

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For C++, [Boost.Random](http://www.boost.org/libs/random/) is probably what you're looking for. It has support for MT (among many other algorithms), and can collect entropy via the `nondet_random` class. Check it out! :-)

Answer (score 8):

[The Gnu Scientific Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl) (GSL) has a pretty extensive set of RN generators, test harness, etc.  If you're on linux, it's probably already available on your system.

Answer (score 7):

Watch out for the Gnu Scientific Library.  It's licensed under the GPL rather than LGPL.

As other folks mentioned, the Boost random classes are a good start.  Their implementation conforms to the PRNG code slated for TR1:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/random/index.html
http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1452.html

If you have a recent version of the G++ compiler, you may find the TR1 libraries already included

Answer (score 5):

C++11 has adopted a robust random number library based on boost.random. You can access a number of random number engines using different algorithms to meet your quality, speed, or size requirements. Quality implementations will even provide access to whatever non-deterministic RNG your platform offers via `std::random_device`.

In addition there are many adaptors to produce specific distributions, eliminating the need to do such manipulation by hand (something often done incorrectly).

[`#include <random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random)

Answer (score 2):

`Boost.Random` is my first choice for RNG

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/random

Comment: You could find Boost random by just googling thats why i dint provide any links. Now i have updated it with the link to lib.